# Check if instance is of object extending an ABC

Tags: python, abc

The structure I have looks like this:

```
Parent(abc.ABCMeta) -> Foo(Parent)

Parent(abc.ABCMeta) -> SubParent(abc.ABCMeta, Parent) -> Bar(SubParent)
```

Then, say we have instances like so,

```
x = Foo()
t = Bar()
```

From this design, is it possible to answer the question,
 `x is _not_ an instance of some abstract class that extends Parent?`

*I understand that taking a high-level look at this might seem like some design smell.*

Comment: Definitely a design smell. Also, `abc.ABCMeta` is a metaclass. If you want to write an abstract base class, you should be using `ABCMeta` as a metaclass, not extending it. Also, `SubParent` doesn't need to re-specify `ABCMeta`.

Comment: @user2357112 ah yes -- its actually a metaclass, in code usage is `@six.add_metaclass(abc.ABCMeta)`. Apologies for the bad representation there. Regardless, I think bad design pattern should be fixed on my part, instead of trying such approaches that _kind of cover it up_. Voting to close the question, post this discussion.